# Conditional deleting rows in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 3 columns. The 1. column has either the value 1 or 0 in the rows. I want to delete all the rows in the matrix, where the 1. column is equal to zero (or keep the rows containing ones).

Thanks.

Comment: `x[x[,1] != 0,]` or `x[x[,1] == 1,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, say that you have this matrix:

```
A= matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3, 8),3,3, byrow=T)
```

The following command will give you a vector of TRUE/FALSE for each row, depending on whether the 1st column is 1 or not:

```
A[,1]==1
```

You can then select only those rows like this:

```
FILTERED = A[A[,1]==1,]
```

And you'll then find what you ask for in `FILTERED`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Oops sorry. Too much octave :) Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#dummy matrix
x <- matrix(rep(c(1,0,1),4),ncol=3)

x
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    1
# [2,]    0    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    0
# [4,]    1    0    1

#keep rows where 1st column equals to 1
x[x[,1] == 1,]
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    1
# [3,]    1    1    0
# [4,]    1    0    1
```